# Android BLE communicating with peripheral disconnects before service discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have a problem when I try to use cheaper Android phones to communicate with our NordicSemi nRF52832 chip.

I can discover the peripheral and then connect, but when I device.discoverServices() the software pauses for about 10 seconds, and then disconnects with the output:

> D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE, auto: false
>   D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() -
>   UUID=b05b54e9-bd20-423f-a6db-461775f954f0 D/BluetoothGatt:
>   onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7 D/BluetoothGatt:
>   onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=7
>   device=CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device:
>   CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() =
>   Device=CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE Status=129 D/BluetoothGatt:
>   onClientConnectionState() - status=22 clientIf=7
>   device=CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device:
>   CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE D/BluetoothGatt: close() D/BluetoothGatt:
>   unregisterApp() - mClientIf=7 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device:
>   CA:E7:8F:03:82:CE D/BluetoothGatt: close() D/BluetoothGatt:
>   unregisterApp() - mClientIf=0

With onServicesDiscovered status = 129

The phones are in this case: Samsung Galaxy J3 (J320FN) & Huawei P8lite (ALE-L21)